# AWS Lambda python function doesn't do anything to my picture

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to resize a picture by using a fixed width of 450, and height being set automatically according to the aspect ratio. This code worked when I made classic thumbnails in PIL before (128x128), so I am not sure why it doesn't work now. It doesn't throw any errors, it just outputs the picture same as before, no changes.

```
import boto3
import os
import sys
import uuid
from PIL import Image
import PIL.Image
     
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
     
def resize_image(image_path, resized_path):
    with Image.open(image_path) as image:
        basewidth = 450
        wpercent = (basewidth / float(image.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(image.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
        image.resize(basewidth,hsize)
        image.save(resized_path)

     
def handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key'] 
        download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)
        upload_path = '/tmp/resized-{}'.format(key)
        
        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
        resize_image(download_path, upload_path)
        s3_client.upload_file(upload_path, '{}-resized'.format(bucket), key)
```

Comment: Share rest of the lambda function. How do you read the image?

Comment: Alright I'll edit it, don't know how that helps tho

Comment: Add few print messages and check cloud watch for the outputs

Comment: Already checked all of that, I said it outputs nothing. Complete success as far as the running of it goes.

Comment: No file is created in the resized bucket?

Comment: The file is created - the problem is nothing is changed. It's the same size as the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with this library, but I'd suggest assigning a new variable on resize. Change this:

```
image.resize(basewidth,hsize)
image.save(resized_path)
```

To this:

```
resizedImage = image.resize(basewidth,hsize)
resizedImage.save(resized_path)
```